# What's the difference between orthography and spelling?

Tags: differences, synonyms, terminology, formality

The terms "spelling" and "orthography" seem to be largely synonymous. What is the difference really? Is it that "orthography" is a more formal or technical term and hence more well-defined? Or is it just a fancy word to make me sound smarter when saying the same thing? (-:

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I agree, they sound similar and synonymous, but they have a definite difference.

Like Lefteris Gkinis said, **orthography** comes from the Greek and means "Correct way of writing".

It includes also punctuation and *spelling*. So, rather than a mere activity, it's the part of the Grammar that studies, and is related to, the correct way of writing, whether it is about single words, punctuation, etc.

The **spelling**, like the NOAD says, is "*the process or activity of writing or naming the letters of a word.*" So it's something more specific, since it's only related to how the single words are "made".

Comment: Why the downvote? Is there some mistake?

Comment: @TsuyoshiIto, Could use the "non-character" characters as fodders, it works, e.g. just type `data:text/html,&#x034f;` in Chrome's URL bar then Ctrl-A Ctrl-C to copy it.  A couple others like `#x200d;` etc used to work too but looks like SE has patched that.

Answer (score 6):

In order to answer your question, we have to first investigate the exact meaning of orthography. Orthography is the standardized procedure of a writing system, which includes punctuation, capitalization, word breaks, emphasis, etc. This means that spelling is only a part of orthography(spelling is part of a writing system), but orthography includes a lot more than just spelling. That is where the difference between orthography and spelling lies.

Answer (score 1):

[This might help.](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=orthography) (http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=orthography)

Interestingly, German *Rechtschreibung* directly translates the Greek.

Comment: The etymology might help, but when it's the meaning you want you always have to keep in mind the "Etymological fallacy" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Etymological_fallacy

Comment: Well I thing the `etymology` is not only "might" help but allways help. It is the leading tool to understand the right use of the words.

Comment: @hippietrail, Lefteris. Yea it depends on each individual word, there's the etymology-fallacy and also the fallacy of the etymological-fallacy.

Answer (score 0):

I take this opportunity to approach the real meaning of this question. I found it very accurate and a nice topic to think about.

The word *orthography* is a Greek word passed as is in the Latin language. In order to understand the meaning we have to divide the word into two parts:

- `ortho` -> `sosto` => the right action (to take, make, write, act). By "right" we mean "following the rules which stand in our life."
- `graphy` -> `grapho` => the verb "write."

Taking the meaning of first word (leading us what to do) and the second word (which field to do that action), it altogether means "do the right in writing" or "correct way of writing."

To [*spell*](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=spell), or "name the letters of", derives from O.E. *spellian* "to tell, speak," via Frankish, Germanic, and Gothic terms, ultimately from PIE *spel-*, "to say aloud, recite."  Also, *spelling* is translated in Greek as `silavismos` which has two meanings:

- To divide a word in certain pieces under certain rules for grammar use
- To divide the word in as many pieces as there are letters (also for grammar use)

This can be done whether the word was written with right rules or not ("un-orthographic").  While "rightness" is built into the word *orthography*, such is not the case with *spelling*.

Thus we conclude that `orthography` and `spelling` are two different words with quite different use and meaning.

Comment: Just for the history I really want to know whos downvote my answer

Comment: @Lefteris: I don't know who downvoted but I assume it is because of the difficulty in understanding your answer. There are a handful of minor grammar and spelling errors which, if fixed, would probably help.

Comment: Yes thats the naked true, I'm not good in orthografy either in Greeks nor in English. So I'll leave it to someone who knows better than me the English grammar to correct my answer. But the importand is for those which they need the real answer to understnad it.

Comment: I hope my editing brings the reader closer to the meaning of my answer. If not please ask me what you don't understand

Comment: @Lefteris: I tried to help by editing the answer. If you don't mind checking it to make sure it still means what you wanted it to mean. :) Also, I was a little confused by the different meanings for "spelling". I don't understand the difference between them.

Comment: The fact the answer explains the meaning of the Greek word for _spelling_ could also be the reason of down voting.

Comment: @MrHen. Yes and thank you very much for your efforts on editing. You see what I want to pass thru my answer was the meaning of the word itself because after all the Greek Language is compose of meanings. If we stay on this, we easily understand the use of the Greek Language which is not standing in a combination (smart or not) of words but it stands on a combination of meanings. I see that when we did not understand something we ask or read or doing all the necessary acts before we express our rejection to a meaning.

Comment: @kiamlaluno. If that what you say is true then I'm really sorry for the person who did that, and the reason for that I’m posting at the end of my previous comment “Ask to Learn before you reject”. But any way I want to thank you very much as well because with your position on my answer you're trying to learn more of it. "I thing"

Comment: Continuing on my answer and taking your positions @MrHen and @kiamlaluno as a question of “Why we have to take the “spelling” word explanation from the Greek Language”?

Comment: My position is that: From the beginning of the answer we’ve try an approach to the word of “orthography” which is a Greek word and also we’ve try to compare the meaning of this word with an English word “spelling”. It’ll be a misstate if we left the words explanation in there mother Language, Thus we NEED to transfer one of them at least to the other Language and in order to do that and because the word “spelling” is not a Greek word we’re transfer the meaning of it and we examine the meanings for both of them in Greeks. There is where my answer stands. Any black spot?

Comment: Dear MrHen I say again this (now based on my previous position), the meaning and translation of the word “spelling” in Greeks is `silavismos` and this word giving us the opportunity to “play” with a word, and in order to “play” with it the Greek Language giving us two ways (rules)

Comment: A) To cut it in certain pieces like si – la – vi – smos. This method giving us the opportunity to use the word in grammar and taking from this (the grammar) the reason of why we have to write this word like that (there is a grammar rule for each one of the pairs) of course in order to be able to understand what I’m saying you need to lookout the word with Greek letters.

Comment: B) To cut it in pieces as many as the letters are “s – i – l – a – v – i – s – m – o – s”. This method is used mostly, even the word is written orthographically or un-orthographically, to “play” with it out of any orthographic rule or grammar rule (most of the time for use in mathematics)

Comment: @Lefteris Gkinis _Orthography_ is an English word that had origin from a Greek word; translating a word in Greek, and reporting what that means in Greek is essentially wrong because the topic of this site is English. If you report from which Greek word the English word has been originated, that is fine, but saying "the Greek word means this; therefore, the English word must mean the same" is not exact. To make an example, it would be like translating _cocoa_ in Spanish, and then reporting that _cacao_ is used in phrases like _pedir cacao_, _ser gran cacao_, or _no valer un cacao_.

Comment: @kiamlaluno. From the point you're taking the word you have absolutely right. But my aim was not that point of view. The word “orthography” is a complete Greek word and is write “ορθογραφία” (I don’t know if that comes to you as is or the letters turn it to symbols) and pass it to the English Language as loan – word (we have many loan – words in Greek Language too), but here the loan comes with each meaning as a package and it used like that.