# Is incorrect capitalization considered a spelling error?

Tags: orthography, terminology, capitalization, errors

Is incorrect capitalization, such as the lowercase "i" in

> [Can] i [this sic] have an if statement within a
>   dialog box code?

considered a spelling mistake, or some other type of error?

Comment: +1 for the Star Wars meme but -1 for making your question really hard to interpret d-;

Comment: Strictly speaking writing the personal pronoun "I" as "i" is NOT a spelling mistake but it is still a writing mistake, which many speakers of foreign languages make. For example, in Italian the equivalent pronoun, io, is always written in small. So, "i" is not necessarily a typo or laziness, it could very well be a "language interference" mistake.

Comment: If i is the name of a method/function, it may not be a capitalization error.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your question was," Is it a spelling mistake?" The answer is definitely no. It is a grammatical error, a capitalization error, but not a spelling error. When you capitalize a word, you don't change its spelling.

Comment: Calling this a grammatical error is kind of inexact and improper.

Comment: Grammar is the study of the syntax and morphology of sentences as well as the features and characteristics in the sentences. Surely capitalization is a characteristic in the sentences

Comment: You're right, it's included, I was slightly wrong. But still, it's too general. If we think like that, _everything_ can be a grammatical error... So it remains inexact, no?

Comment: Nearly... except for things that aren't errors.

Comment: What you said doesn't concern this discussion, actually...

Comment: By which you mean...?

Comment: We aren't talking about situations where there are no mistakes, obviously, so that "except" denotes something we're not talking about, no?

Comment: I already said this answer, if you read other answers before posting a new one.

Comment: I complemented your answer! Yes, I already read your answer, but not the link, actually.

Comment: Grammar is a property of language. Language is naturally occurring spoken or signed human communication. Writing is a recently invented technology to encode natural human language into more permanent markings. Language does not have upper and lower case, those concepts only apply to the technology of writing. When to use capital letters is not grammar, it is orthography - correct writing.

Answer (score 9):

I can almost guarantee that different people will answer this both "yes" and "no".

As a Wiktionary contributor I've found some people can be quite forceful in their insistence that spelling applies only to letters and not to capitalization, hyphens, apostrophes, or to the characters in Chinese or Japanese for that matter.

On the other hand you will find many many sentences like this if you search:

- Do you spell Southwest with a capital w?
- I spell my God's name with a capital “G”.
- They are beginning to be aesthetic, like the rest of the world, beginning to spell truth with a capital T.
- The Atman of Shankara is here spelled with a capital “A” while that of Buddha is spelled with a small “a.”

So it is clear that many people do use the word “spell” to cover use of capital letters.

Comment: An Austrian acquaintance once complained about someone's bad spelling. When I asked for examples, the first he gave was frequent failure to capitalize nouns.

Answer (score 7):

Usually *spelling* refers to putting the [right letters in the right order](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/spelling). Other niceties, such as capitalisation, fall under the more general term of [orthography](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/orthography), which includes [spelling and other aspects of correct writing](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24042/whats-the-difference-between-orthography-and-spelling).

Answer (score 4):

I think it can be categorised differently. If you know it must be capitalised, it might be a simple typo... If you don't know it, then you could consider it an orthographic error.

*Orthography* has this origin (according to NOAD)

> **ORIGIN**: late Middle English, via Old French and Latin from Greek `orthographia`, from *orthos* ‘correct’ + -*graphia* ‘writing.’

Spelling is a part of Orthography, *linguistically* speaking, but as you can see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthography), "*other elements of the field of orthography are hyphenation, capitalization, word breaks, emphasis, and punctuation*".

I think it's what you were looking for.

Comment: I'm asking is it a spelling error, or is it a different type of error?

Comment: I think it can be categorised differently. If you know it must be capitalised, it might be a simple typo... If you don't know it, then you could consider it an orthographic error (I'm not sure it's the same as spelling, but I guess so). Was this what you wanted to know? If not, please be more specific either here on the comments or edit your question.

Comment: @Andrew Grimm: I corrected the answer. I guess I misunderstood your question. :)

Answer (score 1):

We never say, "We grammar a word with a capital letter" because grammar isn't an action word. We do say, "We spell a word with a capital letter" because spell is an action we do when writing. If we make an error doing something, then that action is said to be in error. In this case that would be "spell." This is why we say this is a "spelling error."

Comment: By "action word" did you mean "verb"?

Comment: Phoog, are you trying to make points by commenting? It should be clear I am making a point that the action of spelling is what is done wrong, and not a rule of Grammar which only describes the action of spelling. We can violate a rule, but that violation here is spelling it wrong. We don't do a rule wrong, but we do an action wrong which in this case is spelling.

Answer (score 0):

Is incorrect capitalization considered a spelling error? 
Capitalization is something done while writing, and orthography is the method of spelling words in a printed form. Since Orthography is the method we use to write words, then, other than by accident or ignorance, incorrect capitalization would be considered spelling error. This is because Orthography defines spelling as it is written, but not as it is spoken.

Comment: Isn't "spelling as it is spoken" an oxymoron?

Comment: You can spell a word verbally which isn't what is being asked.

Comment: This is less of an answer than an opinion. You cite no sources, but rather give your interpretation of how orthography relates to capitalization. The help page on how to write a useful answer is an important resource for new users: http://english.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Let us define a few words:

Comment: The definitions of spell and orthography can be looked up at:
 http://www.webster-dictionary.net/definition/spell
There are two ways to spell a word which is written or verbal. To write it is orthography. 
Orthography is definition at:
http://www.webster-dictionary.net/definition/orthography
Orthography is how the word is written down which means incorrect capitalization is a spelling error.

Comment: Also every spelling reference, like the dictionary or spell check, shows the correct spelling with capital letters, when required, which means this is a spelling error if done incorrect.

Answer (score -1):

[Here](http://www.agts.edu/dmin/project/gram_spell_err.pdf), capitalization error is listed under:

```
    "common grammatical errors"
```

And not in spelling errors, but i found somewhere it's also an independent category of error. I think both supposed to be correct.

Comment: No, this is wrong. Capitalization is not about grammar.