# Is there one term for grammar, punctuation and spelling?

Tags: single-word-requests

I"d like to find one term which unites three parts of writing: *grammar, punctuation, and spelling.*

Could **orthography** or **proofreading** be used to describe this?

Comment: Related: [What's the difference between orthography and spelling](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/24042/whats-the-difference-between-orthography-and-spelling)

Comment: My guess is that you're asking for a word that distinguishes the analytical technical components of language from the more humanistic, raw components. How close am I?

Comment: Which components are which, and how do you tell?

Comment: I remember a teacher at school being less than impressed at an exam board’s use of the acronym SPAG for this purpose...

Comment: Only half in jest - perhaps the best single word would be ...education.

Comment: If the question is, "is there a single accepted word that includes grammar, spelling, and punctuation, it is whatever one decides it is. Words mean exactly what I intend them to mean, nothing more or less, to ruin a good quote. However, I'd nominate "English 131."

Answer (score 13):

There isn't really a word that refers to those three things and no others.

Grammar is not a part of writing. It's part of language, which is spoken.

Spoken language, of course, doesn't have any punctuation or spelling, but it does have grammar. And there are a lot of other things that go into writing besides spelling and punctuation.

I fear someone has been misinforming you.

Comment: I'd disagree with this statement quite a bit. Grammar certainly is part of writing, as writing is an expression of language. "He buyed me a cookies" is still ungrammatical despite my writing it and not speaking it.

Comment: If you speak the language, you know the grammar, whether you can discuss it or not. And if you speak the language, you use your knowledge in writing it. That's certainly true. But grammar is only a very small part of the things you use in writing: there's rhetoric, stress, vocabulary choice, construction choice (one aspect of grammar), sociolinguistic factors, audience specialization, et complex cetera. "Grammar" _per se_, especially as taught in Anglophone schools, is largely irrelevant, when it's not downright mythology.

Comment: I wonder what leads you to the belief that this (as I understand you very prescriptivist) way of teaching grammar is especially inherent to Anglophone schools. In my experience, it is almost universal in schools, regardless of language. There is also the fact that written and spoken grammar, generally, are two different things. There is a grammar of language as it is spoken, and a different grammar of language as it is written. Grammar is a part of language, which is spoken _amd written_.

Comment: No, there's only grammar of spoken languages. There are no grammars of written language that are different from spoken grammars; but there are grammars for every spoken language, whether it has ever been written or not. Writing is just technology, a representation of spoken language, which is biological. Same as the difference between one's bicycle and one's legs.

Comment: _"[Grammar is] part of language, which is spoken."_ - Language can be spoken _or_ written. Except some languages _aren't_ spoken, e.g., sign language (which has its own grammar; it isn't a visual representation of standard English). _"But grammar is only a very small part of the things you use in writing"_ - All of the things you list that are done in writing also apply to spoken language. Having said that, I do agree with you that the grammar of a language is not specific to the written form of that language, it does also (and chronologically first) apply to the spoken (or signed) form.

Answer (score 8):

Teachers who assign student writing typically use some kind of rubric listing the various criteria by which the grade for the work is to be calculated. A common term for the criterion that includes grammar, spelling and punctuation is **mechanics**.

Here are is an extract from the online writing rubric by *[readwritethink](http://www.readwritethink.org/files/resources/lesson_images/lesson261/sample.pdf)* under the criterion **Mechanics**:

> *Level 1 = Minimal* : Many spelling, grammar, and punctuation errors; sentence fragments; incorrect use of capitalization
>
> *Level 4 = Outstanding* : Correct spelling, grammar, and punctuation; complete
> sentences; correct use of capitalization

And here is an one from [longwood.edu](http://www.longwood.edu/media/moton-museum/public-site/WritingRubric.pdf) under the criterion **Writing mechanics** (Grammar, Spelling, Punctuation, Citations)

> *Level 4:* The student uses correct grammar, makes essentially no errors of spelling or punctuation, and formats citations (if any)
> correctly.
>
> *Level 0:* The writing's low-level mechanics are so poor that the language is incoherent and difficult to understand.

Comment: I see *[rubric](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rubric)* has a sense I didn't know about: "A printed set of scoring criteria for evaluating student work and for giving feedback".

Comment: That's funny- that's the only sense I *did* know about.

Comment: It's a term of art in religious ceremonials. Like _canon_ and _canonical_ is in religious orthodoxies.

Comment: See also: https://www.msu.edu/~jdowell/135/areaVI.html

Answer (score 5):

After looking up its definitions in several dictionaries, I would not use "orthography" as inclusive of (correct) grammar and punctuation, simply because it means:

1. the conventional spelling system of a language.
2. the study of spelling and how letters combine to represent sounds and form words.

[from the New Oxford American Dictionary]

---

1.
a)  the art of writing words with the proper letters according to standard usage.
b)  the representation of the sounds of a language by written or printed symbols.

1. a part of language study that deals with letters and spelling.

[from the Merriam-Webster Dictionary]

---

Perhaps the use of "orthography" seems pretentious to some, but the evidence, according to the authorities, is strongly in favor of its having to do with spelling, and spelling alone. Incidentally, it's generally recommended to do research before drawing conclusions or stating one's opinions.

Comment: So what is your answer to the OP's question? You have made a comment, pertinent, but still only a comment.

Comment: It is most definitely an answer to the question "Could orthography or proofreading be used to describe this?", which the OP posed. This is what happens when an OP includes several different questions.

Comment: I agree. It's an answer, and it's a correct answer. That's what we're here for.

Comment: The problem is that the title question is different from the body question.  This is not an answer to the title question.

Answer (score 4):

I would use 'orthography' as inclusive of (correct) grammar and punctuation, not solely as a slightly pretentious synonym of 'accepted spelling'.

Answer (score 2):

I just looked at the title for this site; and realized that "English Usage" may best capture the cmbination of Spelling, Punctuation and Grammar.

Answer (score 1):

> S.P.A.G

I forget what the *A* stands for.

Comment: "A" as in *and*.

Answer (score 1):

**Syntax**.

In programming languages, a typo can lead to a [***syntax** error*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax_error).

> In linguistics, [**syntax**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Syntax) (from Ancient Greek σύνταξις "coordination"
>   from σύν syn, "together," and τάξις táxis, "an ordering") is "the
>   study of the principles and processes by which sentences are
>   constructed in particular languages." - Chomsky, Noam (2002) [1957]. Syntactic Structures. p. 11

The correct ordering of symbols covers grammar, punctuation, and spelling.

The correct order is still specified by the language [grammar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammar), though, see [grammaticality](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammaticality).

Comment: Easily the best answer.